# csv to nested json without duplicate values

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I'm working on a API, and i would like to make my Sql database from my csv data, but i need to transform into a json with a particular format...

I don't find yet the solution to change my csv to this special json...

this is my csv data

```
Language,IsoPays,Pays,Regions,States,Cities,Mountains,Bassins,Rivers
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Isère,Saint-Michel-les-Portes,Vercors,Drac,
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Isère,Saint-Andéol,Vercors,Drac,Le Ruisseau de Berrièves
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Isère,Varces-Allières-et-Risset,Vercors,Drac,
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Isère,Engins,Vercors,Isère,
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Isère,Sassenage,Vercors,Isère,
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Isère,Montaud,Vercors,Isère,Ruisseau des Gorges
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Isère,La Rivière,Vercors,Isère,
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Isère,Saint-Gervais,Vercors,Isère,La Drevenne
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Isère,Saint-Gervais,Vercors,Isère,Le ruisseau des grandes routes
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Isère,Rovon,Vercors,Isère,
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Isère,Malleval-en-Vercors,Vercors,Isère,La Gerlette
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Isère,Malleval-en-Vercors,Vercors,Isère,La Serve
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Isère,Izeron,Vercors,Isère,
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Isère,Rencurel,Vercors,Bourne,
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Ain,Seillonnaz,Bugey,,
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Ain,Champagne-en-Valromey,Bugey,,
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Ain,Bénonces,Bugey,Rhône,La Pernaz
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Ain,Villebois,Bugey,,
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Ain,Surjoux,,Rhône,
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Haute-Savoie,Servoz,Chablais - Platé - Aiguilles Rouges,Arve,
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Haute-Savoie,Lovagny,Bornes - Aravis,,
en,FR,France,Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes,Haute-Savoie,Mieussy,Chablais - Platé - Aiguilles Rouges,Giffre,Le Giffre
en,FR,France,Occitanie,Pyrénées-Orientales,Vernet-les-Bains,Canigou,La Tet,
en,FR,France,Occitanie,Pyrénées-Orientales,Thuès-Entre-Valls,Canigou,La Tet,Fajet
en,FR,France,Occitanie,Pyrénées-Orientales,Saint-Paul-de-Fenouillet,Corbières,,L'Agly
en,FR,France,Occitanie,Pyrénées-Orientales,Prats-de-Mollo-la-Preste,Canigou,Le Tech - Vallespir,Le Tech
en,FR,France,Occitanie,Pyrénées-Orientales,Arles-sur-Tech,Albères,Le Tech - Vallespir,Ravin de la Seignoural
en,FR,France,Occitanie,Pyrénées-Orientales,Amélie-les-Bains-Palalda,Albères,Le Tech - Vallespir,Terme
en,FR,France,Occitanie,Pyrénées-Orientales,Céret,Pic des Salines,Le Tech - Vallespir,Le Nogarède
en,FR,France,Occitanie,Pyrénées-Orientales,Nyer,,,
```

and i would like t o get this json, i don't need id it will be made automaticely with visual studio

```
    {
  "id": 0,
  "language": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "iso": "string",
  "regions": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "countryId": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "states": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "countryId": 0,
          "regionId": 0,
          "name": "string",
          "cities": [
            {
              "id": 0,
              "canyonId": 0,
              "countryId": 0,
              "regionId": 0,
              "stateId": 0,
              "name": "string",
              "moutains": [
                {
                  "id": 0,
                  "countryId": 0,
                  "regionId": 0,
                  "stateId": 0,
                  "cityId": 0,
                  "name": "string",
                  "bassins": [
                    {
                      "id": 0,
                      "countryId": 0,
                      "regionId": 0,
                      "stateId": 0,
                      "cityId": 0,
                      "mountainId": 0,
                      "name": "string",
                      "rivers": [
                        {
                          "id": 0,
                          "countryId": 0,
                          "regionId": 0,
                          "stateId": 0,
                          "cityId": 0,
                          "mountainId": 0,
                          "bassinId": 0,
                          "name": "string"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I did this kind of python, but i have some issues:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
pd.options.display.max_rows = None

#df = pd.read_csv ('all_paysdatacanyoncsv.csv')
df = pd.read_csv ('testjsoncountry.csv')

#print(df.columns)

s = df.set_index(df.columns[:-1].tolist())[df.columns[-1]]


def redict(s):
    if s.index.nlevels == 1:
        return s.to_dict()

    else:
        return {k: redict(g.xs(k)) for k, g in s.groupby(level=0)}

redict(s)
```

but the result is not perfect :

```
{'en': {'FR': {'France': {'Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes': {'Ain': {'Belleydoux': {'Jura': {'Rhône': 'Semine'}},
      'Boyeux-Saint-Jérôme': {'Bugey': {nan: nan}},
      'Bénonces': {'Bugey': {'Rhône': nan}},
      'Cerdon': {'Bugey': {nan: nan}},
      'Chaley': {'Bugey': {nan: 'Albarine'}},
      'Champagne-en-Valromey': {'Bugey': {nan: nan}},
      'Champfromier': {'Jura': {nan: nan}},
      'Chézery-Forens': {'Jura': {nan: nan}},
      'Contrevoz': {'Bugey': {nan: nan}},
      'Dortan': {'Jura': {'Bienne': nan}},
      'Hauteville-Lompnes': {'Bugey': {nan: nan}},
      'La Burbanche': {'Bugey': {nan: nan}},
      'Lompnas': {'Bugey': {nan: 'La Brive'}},
      'Montanges': {'Jura': {'Rhône': nan}},
      'Montréal-la-Cluse': {'Bugey': {nan: nan}},
      'Rossillon': {'Bugey': {nan: nan}},
      'Saint-Germain-de-Joux': {},
      'Seillonnaz': {'Bugey': {nan: nan}},
      'Serrières-sur-Ain': {'Bugey': {'Rhône': nan}},
```

I Think I'm close to the solution but i need help.

Thanks a lot for your help ;)

Comment: I cannot understand how the current result is related to the description you gave. Please show (even partially) the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i wasn't very clear, i would like this result:

```
{
  "language": "en",
  "name": "France",
  "iso": "FR",
  "regions": [
    {
      "name": "Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes",
      "states": [
        {
          "name": "Isère",
          "cities": [
            {
              "name": "Saint-Michel-les-Portes",
              "moutains": [
                {
                  "name": "Vercors",
                  "bassins": [
                    {
                      "name": "Drac",
                      "rivers": [
                        {
                          "name": "string"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution and it wasn't easy !!!!! hope it will help someone who need to do the same process.

```
import pprint, json

res = []

coalesce = lambda x: x if x else 'undefined'

country = lambda item: (coalesce(item['NameCountry']), {
    'language': coalesce(item['Language'])
    ,'isoPays': coalesce(item['IsoPays'])
    ,'pays': coalesce(item['NameCountry'])
    ,'Regions': []
})

region = lambda item: (coalesce(item['NameRegion']), {
    'name': coalesce(item['NameRegion'])
    ,'States': []
})

state = lambda item: (coalesce(item['NameStates']), {
    'name': coalesce(item['NameStates'])
    ,'Cities': []
})

city = lambda item: (coalesce(item['NameCity']), {
    'name': coalesce(item['NameCity'])
    ,'Mountains': []
})

mountain = lambda item: (coalesce(item['NameMountain']), {
    'name': coalesce(item['NameMountain'])
    ,'Bassins': []
})

bassin = lambda item: (coalesce(item['NameBassin']), {
    'name': coalesce(item['NameBassin'])
    ,'Rivers': []
})

river = lambda item: (coalesce(item['NameRiver']), {
    'name': coalesce(item['NameRiver'])
})

tree_conf = [
    (country, 'Regions', {})
    ,(region, 'States', {})
    ,(state, 'Cities', {})
    ,(city, 'Mountains', {})
    ,(mountain, 'Bassins', {})
    ,(bassin, 'Rivers', {})
    ,(river, None, {})
]

with open('all_paysdatacanyoncomplete.csv', 'r') as f:
    header = f.readline().strip().split(',')
    for row in f.readlines():
        item = dict(zip(header, row.strip().split(',')))
        last = res
        for conf in tree_conf:
            key, value = conf[0](item)
            if not key in conf[2]:
                conf[2][key] = value
                last.append(value)
            if conf[1]:
                last = conf[2][key][conf[1]]

with open('res.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(res, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```